# Angular Pull-to-refresh doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement a Pull-to-refresh angular component. I am really new to Angular, but Chrome Developer Tools doesn't display any errors.

For more info see: https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-pull-to-refresh/blob/master/readme.md

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <style>
        body { background:blue; }
        * {
            /*-webkit-user-select: none; */
            /*-webkit-touch-callout: none; */
        }

    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pull-to-refresh.css">
    <script src="pull-to-refresh.js"></script>


    <script>

        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['mgcrea.pullToRefresh']);

        angular.module('myApp')

            .controller('NetworkCtrl', function($scope) {

            $scope.refresh = function() {
                alert('refresh!');
            };

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="NetworkCtrl">

    <div class="content" pull-to-refresh="refresh()" style="background:yellow">
        test<br>
        test<br>
        test<br>
        test<br>
        test<br>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where have you saved "pull-to-refresh.js", is it being included? is it being initialized? etc etc.  Please provide more information.

Comment: I verified that the JS file is being loaded and there are no errors in the console log. I suppose the entire file not loading will at least cause an error because of failing dependency injection. I was hoping I made a logically error somewhere.

Comment: angular.module('myApp')--- BIG GAP--.controller(    is this "BIG GAP" in your actual code? or just an anomaly from copy paste?

Comment: The big gap is in the code. It seems to be common practice in Angular to do this.

Comment: Have you tried to add `-webkit-overflow-scroll: touch` from their readme ?

Comment: @koen Did you solved your problem? if yes please provide the solution

Comment: @RezaRahmati, sorry for the delay. I can't recall I fixed the issue.